# Recursive query using CTE

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

So I'm in oracle and using dba_dependencies in order to generate a table of dependencies.  I want to recursively go through the dependencies using CTE.

```
 with recurs (name, owner, type, rname, rowner, rtype,  lvl ) as (
   select name, owner, type, referenced_name, referenced_owner, referenced_type,  1
   from dba_dependencies
   where referenced_name =:object_name

  union all

   select a.name,a.owner, a.type, a.referenced_name,a.referenced_owner, a.referenced_type, r.lvl + 1
   from dba_dependencies a inner join recurs  r
   on r.name = a.referenced_name
    and r.owner = a.referenced_owner
    and r.type = a.referenced_type 
 ) 

 select * 
 from recurs;
```

But there seems to be a problem, it returns a very short list, not matching the number of dependencies.  Anyone know what the problem could be?  Thank you!

Comment: If there's a problem with the data returned then you need to provide the input data, the current output data and the expected output data. Create a minimal dataset that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: `referenced_name, referenced_name` ? Maybe `referenced_name, referenced_owner`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan thank you for pointing out that mistake! but unfortunately it was not the problem

Comment: I think I've got a fairly good idea about what this code snippet does, but you aren't explaining what it is *supposed* to do, so I can't judge whether the problem is e.g. in the logic implementation or elsewhere. So far this seems no more than a guessing game, because I have no example to run your code on and no expected output to compare the results to.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to use `CONNECT BY`

```
SELECT *
FROM dba_dependencies
START WITH referenced_name =:object_name
CONNECT BY PRIOR name = referenced_name
and owner = referenced_owner
and type = referenced_type
```